# PHP test server environment and compatibility before running your code on a new server

Tags: php

So, you're working on a PHP project, you're probably testing it on your local computer at first on an xampp server or another server.

Everything works fine, so you move the site on a server. Probably a shared host. On this host you probably won't have the same PHP version, same extensions available or some functions disabled by the provider for security reasons.

So I think it would be good practice to have a script, that you run the first time when you transfer the project on the new server, and test that all the functions or extensions that you use in your project.

I know wordpress or several other php apps do this at installing, and notify you in case any needed extensions not found, or you need to change certain permissions for a folder.

Does anyone have any examples of how you would go about this? Should you make a foreach loop with all the functions you use in your project and test with function_exists or is_callable?

Any tutorial or guidlines for this? Cause I'm thinking of implementing this for my projects. It would save a lot of time and prevent issues when you move the code to the customer's server for example.

I know there's PHP compatibility checkers or other plugins. But I'm thinking this would be easier and more specific.

Comment: If it's related to the PHP version, you can request that they upgrade it.

Comment: Before you reinvent any wheels - have you considered using (/do you know about) composer? _"Composer is an application-level dependency manager for the PHP programming language that provides a standard format for managing dependencies of PHP software and required libraries."_  (Quote WikiPedia) https://getcomposer.org

Comment: @CBroe: I'm not using any libraries or any third party scripts. I'm just writing plain PHP script and using it's native functions. But let's say you make an application and give it to the customer. They will upload it via FTP on their server. When they set up the app the first time, you want to have a script that checks that your code will run properly on their server, and make them aware if something isn't compatible.

Comment: You could/should also look into Docker - you can set up your local env to match production.

Comment: If you're deploying to multiple customer servers which you don't control, you should provide them in advance with a list of all the system requirements for your software so that they can set it up correctly before attempting installation. That's what most vendors do.

Comment: `I know wordpress or several other php apps do this at installing, and notify you in case any needed extensions not found, or you need to change certain permissions for a folder. Does anyone have any examples of how you would go about this` ...wordpress is open-source I believe, so you could go and look exactly how they do it.

Comment: Better to have a testing/development environment that mirrors your production environment.

Comment: @SimonGoater I think the issue here is that the OP isn't deploying to a single production environment which they control. Instead the software is deployed onto multiple customer-provided environments. Therefore it's difficult to make the dev environment match production. Several viable solutions to that have already been mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: @ADyson Testing by implementation is okay for some scenarios, but not others.

Comment: @SimonGoater Not really sure what you mean by that exactly? The point is that the OP needs to decide what their system requirements are for the software, develop against those, and then inform customers of the requirements. They can do that up-front, before installation, by providing documentation. They can also try to develop a sophisticated installation routine which will check the system requirements automatically before proceeding with setup. Or they could opt to deploy a containerised app with all dependencies pre-packaged. All of which has been suggested above.